# how many ways 3 pairs can be selected out of 6 students?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Out of ***"6 students"*** how many ways can ***3 pairs*** be selected for assigning homework ?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried (6C2) × (4C2) × (2C2) which is wrong I think. Coz I cross checked it by brute force method and found some repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

You select the first pair by ${6\choose2}$ number of ways, the next pair by ${4\choose2}$ and the third pair by ${2\choose2}$.  So the total number of ways you can select three pairs for assigning homework is $\left({6\choose2}{4\choose2}{2\choose2}\right)/3!$ = 15 ways.  You divide by 3! to eliminate order.

Answer (score 5):

Selecting  **a pair** means choosing 2 students out of the collection.

Let us choose first pair: We have 6 students and so this can be done in $6\choose 2$ ways.

Now time to choose the second pair: We are left now with 4 students and so it can be done in $4\choose 2$ ways.

Thus last pair can be chosen in $2\choose 2$ ways

So **it seems that** required number of ways of choosing is $6\choose 2$ $\times$ $4\choose 2$ $\times$ $2\choose 2$

**But wait**,there are repeatations: So to avoid choosing same "3 pairs" more than once,we have to divide it by total number of permutations of 3 pairs which is $3!=6$.

Hence answer is $\frac{1}{6}$$6\choose 2$ $\times$ $4\choose 2$ $\times$ $2\choose 2$

Comment: Yes I got it ! Thanx a lot "usermath".

Comment: You are welcome..